# How to store templated objects in an STL container and member function call

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11, pointer-to-member

Suppose you have a class like

```
template<class T>
struct A {
  void foo() {
    // Need access to "T" here
    typedef typename someTrait<T>::someType T2;
  }
};
```

and you would like to "register" (or store) instances of the class (or a pointers to it) with a container (probably STL) for later calling the `foo()` method of all registered instances.

Since instances instantiated with different template parameters are to be stored (`A<int>`, `A<float>`, ...) obviously one can't use a `std::vector` and store the instances or pointers to it. What I can imagine is making the method `static` and storing function pointers to `void foo()`, like:

```
 void static foo();

 typedef void (* fooPtr)(void);
 std::vector<fooPtr>
```

But somehow I have the feeling this is not very C++11-ish. Is there a nice solution which introduces a wrapper class or something?

Introducing a base class and using dynamic cast would introduce dependencies on `RTTI`, right? I would like to avoid dependencies on `RTTI`.

How would one do this in C++11? (I would not like to introduce additional dependencies like linking to Boost or depending on `RTTI`.)

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: `Obviously one can't use a std::vector since the class is templated` is an incorrect statement. Do you need a vector of objects or a vector of function pointers?

Comment: You are right. That was a sloppy statement. I think I meant a `vector` of different types due to differently instantiated class templates is not possible. Function pointers are enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you could just use virtual methods? This works with C++03 too.

```
struct ABase {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct A : ABase {
    virtual void foo() override {
        // Access to "T" here
    }
};

...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ABase>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new A<int>());
vec.emplace_back(new A<float>());

for (auto& p_a : vec)
    p_a->foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you drop some words why you have chosen the `unique_ptr` ?

Comment: @Frank: So that the instance can be correctly deallocated when the vector goes out of scope. You could use `shared_ptr` too.

Comment: I think virtual function is what I was looking for. It directly answers the question on how to store templated objects. Right answer and +1 for this

Comment: @Frank, KennyTM, I have asked an expansion of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13865853/836097) - please pitch in if you done it as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you actually need an array of functions, you can use `std::function` with conjunction to `std::bind`

```
std::vector<std::function<void()> vec;
A<int> a;
vec.push_back(std::bind(&A<int>::foo, &a)); //now a should live at least as long, as vec
// or vec.push_back(std::bind(&A<int>::foo, a)); - now a will be _copied_ to vec
```

`foo` now is a memeber function (`std::bind` 'binds' the function to given variable here)

Comment: Note that the function will refer to invalid content if `vec` lives longer than `a`. You should just use `std::bind(&A::foo, a)` or create a shared_ptr for the 2nd element.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with `std::bind(&A::foo, &a)`. `A` is a class template and need a template parameter.

Comment: You can fix it with `std::bind(&A<int>::foo, &a)`.