# How to store templated heterogeneous objects in an STL container

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, generics, stl

The question is about a code developed in MS Visual C++ 11, with access only to STL, no Boost.

There is a wrapper template class, roughly with this header:

```cpp
template <typename Payload>
class Wrapper {
  Payload p;
  std::string src;
  Wrapper( std::string, Payload );

  Payload get();      // returns payload
  void set(Payload);  // replaces payload
  void operator ()(); // uses payload
}
```

`Payload` may be anything - pointer, int, even heavy object.

Later, `Wrapper`s need to go in a container, like `std::vector` - but regardless of their specific parameter type. And that gives me trouble because container needs homogeneous elements.

I have tried the base class suggestions [like this from KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065363/836097), however it gives me some issues with methods `get()` and `set()` - those need cast (?) when used from a vector because elements look like a base class if used in the pattern suggested by that answer.

Comment: You need type-erasure class such as `boost::any` which you can implement yourself, so you can avoid Boost.

Comment: KennyTM's solution is only applicable if you actually can use virtual functions. Which you can't here because the return types of your functions are incompatible. Additionally, it doesn't matter much that objects are just different by template parameter. They are still distinct types with different sizes and that is what is most important for containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename Payload>
struct Wrapper;

struct WrapperBase {
  std::string src;
  WrapperBase( std::string s ):src(s) {}
  template<typename Payload>
  Payload get() const;
  template<typename Payload>
  void set(Payload);
  virtual void operator ()() = 0; // uses payload
};

template <typename Payload>
struct Wrapper {
  Payload payload;
  Wrapper( std::string s, Payload p ):WrapperBase(s),payload(p) {}

  Payload get() const { return payload; };      // returns payload
  void set(Payload p) { payload = p; };  // replaces payload
  virtual void operator()() override; // todo
}

template<typename Payload>
Payload WrapperBase::get() const {
  Assert(dynamic_cast<Wrapper<Payload> const*>(this));
  return static_cast<Wrapper<Payload> const*>(this)->get();
}
template<typename Payload>
void WrapperBase::set(Payload p) {
  Assert(dynamic_cast<Wrapper<Payload>*>(this));
  static_cast<Wrapper<Payload>*>(this)->set(p);
}
```

Users of a `WrapperBase`, if they want to set/get the payload, need to know what the type of the payload is.   You can use `dynamic_cast<Wrapper<Payload>*>` to figure out if a given `WrapperBase` is a specific kind if you don't know.

This doesn't have value semantics, so you'll want to store a `vector` of smart pointers to `WrapperBase` rather than actual instances.  `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` are good candidates with very different behavior.

If there is a finite bounded set of `Payloads`, a visitor pattern can work.

If you need value semantics, a `pImpl` pattern that stores the actual payload can do that with manual `operator=` that clones the `pImpl`.

Asking "do you hold type `T`" is possible, but generally is similar to a `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Interesting, so I missed templating of methods in the base class, among other things. Thank you, trying it now.

Answer (score 5):

For that you will need to use some sort of type erasure. From the most basic (provide a base type, store the elements by pointer to the base) to fancier solutions like boost::any you get to choose (I know you mentioned no boost, but you can always take a look at the implementation). Alternatively you could use a *variant* approach (similar to boost::variant) if the set of payloads is known and relatively small, but that might be harder to implement for a single use.